# How to get the equivalence classes for $m(x) = x^2+1$ in $\mathbb Z_{2}[x]$?

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

For $m(x) = x^2+1$ in $\mathbb Z_{2}[x]$, we have

$$\frac{\mathbb Z_{2}[x]}{ \langle x^2+1 \rangle} = \{0, 1, x, x+1\}$$

How do we get that set? I think it's supposed to be a set containing all possible remainders?

Comment: Note that this is: $0x + 0$, $0x + 1$, $1x + 0$, $1x + 1$

Comment: I see, so if I was working in $\mathbb Z_{3}$ would it be $0x+0,  0x+1, 0x+2, 1x+0, 1x+1, 1x+2$? and is this true for all $m(x)$? What if $m(x) = x^3 + 5$ instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a set of all possible remainders. Since you are dividing by a polynomial of degree two, the remainder must be of degree at most 1; since you are working over ${\bf Z}_2$, the coefficients must be 0 or 1; that's the list of all polynomials of degree at most 1, with coefficients 0 or 1.

Comment: So if I was working in $\mathbb Z_{3}[x]$ instead, the coefficients must be 0, 1 or 2, and the list of polynomials must be degree at most 1 with coefficients 0, 1 or 2, ie $\{0, 1, 2, x, x+1, x+2, 2x, 2x+1, 2x+2\}$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$